# Draw a chart using highchart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am very new to data visulizations.
Currently we are having a requirement to draw a  chart similar to below using HighChart.js
[image]

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/22/ for what I tried so far.
I am successfully able to draw chart but facing issue while drawing lines between the datalabel and point (just shown in above image)?
Can you please help?

See below code to draw a chart:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
    },
    xAxis: {
      visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return null
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: false,
            formatter: function(){
            console.log("X"+this.x)
            console.log("this.x%2"+this.x%2)
          if(this.x%2 == 0){
          console.log("in if")
          return "<div style='position: relative;height:70px; border-left:solid thin #ff0000;margin-left:10px'><span style='position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0;'>hello</span></div>";
          }else{
          console.log("in else")
          return "<span style='color:black'>"+this.key+"</span><div style='height:70px; border-left:solid thin #ff0000;margin-left:10px'/>";
          }
          },
          useHTML:true

        }
      },scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                            lineColor: "#ffb74d"
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [{
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80

        },
        marker: {
          radius: 3
        },
        name: 'SDS',
        color: "#ffb74d"
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 5
        },
        name: 'MIP',
        color:"#ffe0b2"
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80,
          distance : 50,
                    softConnector : false,
                    connectorColor : '#D0D0D0',
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 7
        },
        name: 'MDP',
        color:"#ff9800"
      },{
        x: 4,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 9
        },
        name: 'RAD',
        color:"#ffb74d"
      },{
        x: 5,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 3
        },
        name: 'SDS',
        color: "#ffb74d"
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 5
        },
        name: 'MIP',
        color:"#ffe0b2"
      }, {
        x: 7,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 7
        },
        name: 'MDP',
        color:"#ff9800"
      },{
        x: 8,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 9
        },
        name: 'RAD',
        color:"#ffb74d"
      },{
        x: 9,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 3
        },
        name: 'SDS',
        color: "#ffb74d"
      }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 5
        },
        name: 'MIP',
        color:"#ffe0b2"
      }, {
        x: 11,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: -80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 7
        },
        name: 'MDP',
        color:"#ff9800"
      },{
        x: 12,
        y: 1,
         dataLabels: {
          y: 80
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 9
        },
        name: 'RAD',
        color:"#ffb74d"
      }]
    }]

  });
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Any chance you are using angular for this?

Comment: Yes, we are using anugular and bootstrap.css

Comment: Seems like a bubble chart to me, with an added limitation that the y value is constant (let's assume zero). You would of course have to write your own logic for the labels to offset them like that but HC provides callbacks for that and you can style the chart components with CSS. This could be a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/pfz92540/1/. If it turns out too much hassle to do it with HC and you just need this for one chart, writing it from scratch or with a visualization library like d3.js might be faster.

Comment: I also thought about bubble chart: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/ Or standard scatter chart: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński : Thank you, I tried your solution and it works for me pretty much http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/22/ . However, I am not able to draw a line between data labels and markers. I have tried custom formatter but does not look elegent. Can you please help?

Comment: You can use renderer for drawing this labels yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/29/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński : Perfect!!!....It works for me like champ :-), Can you please make it to answer, so that I can accept the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make similar chart you can use bubble chart: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/

Or standard scatter chart: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/1/

You can change marker size of scatter using marker.radius parameter:

```
    marker: {
      radius: 5,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineColor: "#ffb74d"
        }
      }
    },
```

You can add your labels using chart.renderer.path and chart.renderer.label: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label

```
  var drawLabels = function(chart) {
    $('.cLabels').remove();
    var series = chart.series,
      renderer = chart.renderer,
      plotTop = chart.plotTop,
      plotLeft = chart.plotLeft;
    Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
      Highcharts.each(s.data, function(p) {
        renderer.path(['M', p.plotX + plotLeft, p.plotY + plotTop, 'L', p.plotX + plotLeft, p.plotY + plotTop - 30]).attr({
          stroke: 'black',
          'stroke-width': 1
        }).addClass('cLabels').add();
        renderer.label(p.name, p.plotX + plotLeft, p.plotY + plotTop - 50).attr({
          'text-anchor': 'middle',
          padding: 0
        }).addClass('cLabels').add();
      });
    });
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpz2ru5/29/

Answer (score 2):

Your chart seems to be of a specific kind. I personally have not seen any such visualizations before. Also, having worked with HighCharts, I doubt if any `type` of highchart can be transformed as yours.

However, on the first look on your figure the following idea appeared in my mind with angular framework.

You can achieve this kind of visualization using basic html and css.

Assuming you are aware with Angular terminology. I suggest having a list of all your values. Loop them in a simple div as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat = "c in pointsList" > </div>
```

Next you can use `ng-style` or `ng-class` to add dynamic css to your each div.

Seeing your figure, I assume you only following css properties:
1. `border-radius`
2. `background-color`
3. `width`
4. `height`

Seems like you have fixed categories for each type of bubbles. So you can make few fixed classes in your css and apply them dynamically on the basis of your type of point. Basically, it would look like:

```
<div ng-repeat = "c in pointsList" ng-class = "{'css1' : c.type1, 'css2' : c.type2}" > </div>
```

Along with this you will need to apply `display: inline-block` to bring all `divs` in a line.

I know, its too naive solution, but if you have limited requirements of such chart, this can help you achieve it with minimal adjustments.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, will have  try.